# Android 4.3 Webview not scrolling when soft keypad is displayed for form fields

Tags: android, webview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a normal Webview which displays a form. The form has many fields, so if I focus on a field which is in the lower part of the screen the webview does not scroll and the softkeypad hides the input fields.
I have get this problem only n 4.3 (I am testing on Nexus 4)

PS : the Same Webview works on 4.2 and below.

Is this a known issue or is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly set `webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);` - just for the sake of it ?

Comment: just tried setting vertical scroll bar, no luck !

Answer (score 0):

DId you try Scrollview with webview and both inside a Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_header"
    >

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />   

</ScrollView>
```

Try and set verticalscrolling to true.